# Is this use of the expression "very far from" grammatically correct?

Tags: word-in-context

I wouldn't say that it's not a good hotel, but it's very far from being as elegant and charming as it used to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct and perfectly natural sounding.